# Asp.net configuration not able to connect to my .mdf file in APP_Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am running into two main problems, which I believe may be related to each other.

1. When I run the asp.net configuration to set up the provider, it cannot connect.
2. While running the project, when I try to register a new user I get this error:
   "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again."

This is in an MVC4 project, default Internet Application Template. I haven't changed anything in the project other than generating the DB using the code first approach. The database was created the APP_DATA folder. I can connect to it fine in Server Explorer in VS2012, and that connection is coming from this connection string in the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|Data Directory|\NerdlyThings.Models.NerdlyContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=90" />
```

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: did you tried to publish mdf ? more info : http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/11/04/deploying-the-aspnetdb-mdf-to-a-production-server.aspx

Comment: I don't see that option in Visual Studio 2012